# Cisco packet tracer isn't displayed in Activities

Tags: cisco, activities-overview

I installed Cisco Packet Tracer 7.0 on Ubuntu 18.04 but I don't have it displayed in Activities so I have to start it from Terminal every time. How can I make shortcut of Packet Tracer to Activities so I can start it from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom `.desktop` launcher for Cisco Packet Tracer. To do that create a text file, say `packet-tracer.desktop` in `~/.local/share/applications/` directory. You can do this by running the following command in Terminal

```
touch ~/.local/share/applications/packet-tracer.desktop
```

Open the file with the text editor by running

```
gedit ~/.local/share/applications/packet-tracer.desktop
```

Add something like the following to the file and save the file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Launch Cisco Packet Tracer
Terminal=false
Name=Cisco Packet Tracer
Exec=command-to-launch-packet-tracer
Type=Application
Icon=/full/path/to/your/preferred/icon-image
NoDisplay=false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command:

```
sudo cp /opt/pt/bin/packet-tracer.desktop /usr/share/applications/
```

It works for me

But you could also try

```
sudo ln -s /opt/pt/bin/packet-tracer.desktop /usr/share/applications/packet-tracer.desktop
```

Comment: the filename of the `.desktop` file is changed to `Cisco-PacketTracer.desktop`. one upvote for the easiest solution. ;-)